# What is the fastest way to find all squares in an array of points?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, combinations, computational-geometry

The main problem of my program is speed. I mean it works, but terribly slowly.

I have an array of points and I need to find squares here, so in order to do this I need to check all possible combinations of 4 points. So I used three nested loops. In general it would take about n⁴ operations.

If I had up to 100 elements in the array it would be more or less normal, but I have 500 elements, so 500⁴, which is quite a lot. Is here any faster way to do this?

```
/*j, o, k, l are numbers of each point. This loop will check all possible combinations
    (except 2 or more points have the  same number(it means also the same coordinades) or they already are part of some figure*/ 
    for (int j=0; j < i-1; j++)
    {      
        if (Point[j].p != true)
        {
            for (int o = 1; o < i - 2; o++)
            {
                if ((o != j) && (Point[o].p != true))
                {
                    for (int k = 2; k < i - 3; k++)
                    {
                        if ((k!= j) && (k != o) && (Point[k].p != true))
                        {
                            for (int l = 3; l < i - 4; l++)
                            {
                                if ((l != k) && (Point[l].p != true) && (l != o) && (l!=j))
                                {
                                    vx1 = abs(Point[o].x - Point[j].x); //vectors coordinates
                                    vx2 = abs(Point[k].x - Point[o].x);
                                    vy1 = abs(Point[o].y - Point[j].y);
                                    vy2 = abs(Point[k].y - Point[o].y);
                                    vx3 = abs(Point[l].x - Point[k].x);
                                    vy3 = abs(Point[l].y - Point[k].y);
                                    vx4 = abs(Point[j].x - Point[l].x);
                                    vy4 = abs(Point[j].y - Point[l].y);
                                    dx1 = abs(Point[k].x - Point[j].x); //diagonals coordinates
                                    dy1 = abs(Point[k].y - Point[j].y);
                                    dx2 = abs(Point[o].x - Point[l].x);
                                    dy2 = abs(Point[o].y - Point[l].y);
                                    v1 = sqrt(vx1 * vx1 + vy1 * vy1); // sides length
                                    v2 = sqrt(vx2 * vx2 + vy2 * vy2);
                                    v3 = sqrt(vx3 * vx3 + vy3 * vy3);
                                    v4 = sqrt(vx4 * vx4 + vy4 * vy4);
                                    d1 = sqrt(dx1 *dx1 + dy1 * dy1); //diagonals length
                                    d2 = sqrt(dx2 * dx2 + dy2 * dy2);
                                    if (
                                        ((abs(v1-v2)<=0.5) && (abs(v3-v4)<=0.5) && (abs(v3-v2)<=0.5) && (v1<d1)) /*cheks all  sides are equal and if the diagonal is bigger than side*/  
                                        && (Point[k].p != true && Point[o].p != true && Point[j].p != true)/*checks if the points aren`t the part of any figure yet*/ 
                                        &&(abs(d1 - d2)<=0.5)/*checks if the diagonals are equal*/)
                                    {
                                        q++;
                                        Point[j].p = true; // it means that point with this number is already a part of some figure, so it will be skipped in next operations
                                        Point[o].p = true;
                                        Point[k].p = true;
                                        Point[l].p = true;
                                        // the output
                                        out << "Figure " << q << ":" << "x1=" << Point[j].x << " y1=" << Point[j].y << " x2="
                                            << Point[o].x << " y2=" << Point[o].y <<
                                            " x3=" << Point[k].x << " y3=" << Point[k].y <<
                                            " x4=" << Point[l].x << " y4=" << Point[l].y << endl;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you could use a gpu

Comment: `(Point[k].p != true && Point[o].p != true && Point[j].p != true)` seems redundant in the innermost loop since they are already checked outside. Do you need the `sqrt` or could you compare squared values?

Comment: Once you choose two vertices of a square, you know where the other two are on the plane and you only need to check if they are in your set of points. There is no need to check every point for this, and there is definitely no need to calculate any square roots.

Comment: What if you have two squares `{{0,0}, {1,1}}` and `{{2,0}, {3,1}}` and you happen to find the `{{1,0}, {2,1}}` square first instead? It seems you will discard the two original squares in your code.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what your code is supposed to do. Sorting the points in some way will likely enable checking fewer points

Comment: My code should check combinatoins of 4 points and, if these point create square, write them to the file. It writes not only straight  squares, but also rotated

Comment: @В'ячеславІванчук What about discarding the "wrong" squares as I asked about above? The points `{0,0}, {0,1}, {1,0}, {1,1}, {2,0}, {2,1}, {3,0}, {3,1}` can form 2 squares but also the square `{1,0}, {1,1}, {2,0}, {2,1}`  and if that is found first the two squares are discarded.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes that a problem, but to check not only combinations, but also how efficient they are and how many other combinations they discard, we need to improve complexity even more

Comment: @В'ячеславІванчук Can you verify that you are fine with getting only one of the possible squares as your original code does it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well, I think yes.

Comment: @В'ячеславІванчук :-) Ok, that wasn't a 100% **yes** so I added an alternative solution to my answer.

Comment: @В'ячеславІванчук "*Now, after I fixed the errors, the main problem of this program is speed. I mean it works, but terribly slow.*" - then this is probably better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Remy, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se], as it's missing the crucial definitions of types such as `Point`. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned it's a *"computer graphics coordinate system(without negative coordinates)"* I'm also assuming integer values which makes it rather straight forward.

- Create a `std::unordered_set` of `Point`
- For each combination of two points, `A` and `B`, calculate the position of a third point, `C`, rotated 90° in relation to the first two, `A -> B`.
- If such a third point exists in the set, calculate the position of the last point, `D`, in relation to `B -> C`.
- If a match is found, remove the four points from the set.
- Continue until you've gone through all points.

Example:

First, a `Point` class template:

```cpp
template <class T = unsigned long long> // or some other integer type
struct Point {
    bool operator==(const Point& o) const { return x == o.x && y == o.y; }
    bool operator!=(const Point& o) const { return !(*this == o); }

    Point& operator-=(const Point& o) {
        x -= o.x;
        y -= o.y;
        return *this;
    }

    T x, y;
};

template <class T>
Point<T> operator-(const Point<T>& lhs, const Point<T>& rhs) {
    Point rv = lhs;
    rv -= rhs;
    return rv;
}

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point<T>& p) {
    return os << '{' << p.x << ',' << p.y << '}';
}

template <class T>
struct std::hash<Point<T>> {
    std::size_t operator()(const Point<T>& p) const {
        std::hash<T> h;
        // boost::hash_combine:
        std::size_t rv = h(p.x);
        rv ^= h(p.y) + 0x9e3779b9 + (rv << 6) + (rv >> 2);
        return rv;
    }
};
```

This will let us do `B - A` to get a `Point` with the `x` and `y` difference and the specialized `std::hash` will let us store it in containers like `std::unordered_set` that requires the *Key* to be hashable. The `operator<<` overload is just to make printing `Point<>` instances easier.

Next, a function template to get a `Point<>` from rotating 90° in relation to two other `Point<>`s:

```cpp
template<class T>
Point<T> rot90(const Point<T>& A, const Point<T>& B) {
    // C.x = B.x + (B-A).y
    // C.y = B.y - (B-A).x
    auto BA = B - A;
    return {B.x + BA.y, B.y - BA.x};
}
```

Then doing the actual matching could look like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::unordered_set<Point<>> points{ /* ... */ };

    // first, second, third and last iterator:
    // fit(A), sit(B), tit(C), lit(D)
    for (auto fit = points.begin(); fit != points.end();) {
        bool found = false;

        // temporarily extract the node from the set to loop over the rest
        // of the nodes:
        auto next = std::next(fit);
        auto node = points.extract(fit);
        
        // loop over the rest of the nodes:
        auto sit = points.begin();
        decltype(sit) tit, lit;

        for(; sit != points.end(); ++sit) {
            // calculate where C should be:
            auto candidate = rot90(node.value(), *sit);
            if(tit = points.find(candidate); tit != points.end()) {
                // third Point found - try for the last too:
                candidate = rot90(*sit, candidate);
                if(lit = points.find(candidate); lit != points.end()) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(found) {
            std::cout << "FOUND: " << node.value() << ' ' << *sit << ' '
                                   << *tit << ' ' << *lit << '\n';
            // erase the points from the set
            if(next == sit) ++next; // next being erased, step next
            points.erase(sit);
            if(next == tit) ++next; // next being erased, step next
            points.erase(tit);
            if(next == lit) ++next; // next being erased, step next
            points.erase(lit);
        } else {
            // reinsert the first Point node since no square was found
            points.insert(fit, std::move(node));
        }
        fit = next; // try next
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MzrsGMMv1)

---

#### Note:

For certain combinations of points you may find fewer squares than expected. For example, the above algorithm (as well as your original algorithm) may find 1 *or* 2 squares here:

```
{100,1} {101,1} {101,0} {100,0}
{102,1} {103,1} {103,0} {102,0}
```

That's because the points

```
{101,0} {101,1} {102,1} {102,0}
```

also forms a (third) square and since you remove the points already used, the other two will not show up if the above is found first. If you instead want all to show all three you can collect them in another set. I'll use a `std::set` to store the squares which requires `operator<` for the `Square` objects. To simplify the implementation of the `Square::operator<`, first add `Point::operator<`:

```
    bool operator<(const Point& o) const {
        return std::tie(x, y) < std::tie(o.x, o.y);
    }
```

Then, the `Square` class template:

```cpp
template<class T = unsigned long long>
class Square {
public:
    // this requires the points to be added in the order you'd "paint" them,
    // that is, in the order they were found by the matching algorithm below
    Square(Point<T> A, Point<T> B, Point<T> C, Point<T> D) : points{A, B, C, D} {
        // rotate to put the "smallest" Point first
        auto mit = std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end());
        std::rotate(points.begin(), mit, points.end());
    }

    bool operator<(const Square& o) const {
        return points < o.points; // uses Point::operator< 
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Square<T> &s) {
        return os << '{' << s.points[0] << ',' << s.points[1] << ',' 
                         << s.points[2] << ',' << s.points[3] << '}';
    }

private:
    std::array<Point<T>, 4> points;
};
```

And the matching becomes somewhat even more straight forward:

```cpp
template<class T>
auto FindSquares(const std::unordered_set<Point<T>>& points,
                 std::set<Square<T>>& sq_found)
{
    //auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // loop over all points
    for (auto fit = points.begin(), end = points.end(); fit != end; ++fit) {
        // loop over all the other points
        for(auto sit = points.begin(); sit != end; ++sit) {
            if(sit == fit) continue;

            // try to find the third point:
            if(auto tit = points.find(rot90(*fit, *sit)); tit != points.end())
            {
                // third Point found - try for the last too:
                if(auto lit = points.find(rot90(*sit, *tit)); lit != points.end())
                {
                    // store this square (if it's not there already)
                    sq_found.emplace(*fit, *sit, *tit, *lit);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    //return std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start;
}
```

```
int main() {
    std::unordered_set<Point<>> points{/* ... */};
    std::set<Square<>> sq_found;

    FindSquares(points, sq_found);

    for(auto& sq : sq_found) {
        std::cout << "FOUND: " << sq << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zbexEv4Th)

---

I made a few measurements of the `FindSquares` function above when placing points at random places. The durations are only meant to show how it scales:

| Dimensions | Points | Squares found | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 590x591 | 1500 | 1-6 | 0.04s |
| 590x591 | 15000 | 35050 | 5.65s |
| 590x591 | 30000 | 565800 | 31.00s |
| 1777x1057 | 1500 | 0 | 0.04s |
| 1777x1057 | 15000 | 1000 | 5.40s |
| 1777x1057 | 30000 | 15700 | 27.70s |

[image]

Comment: I would not remove the four points from the set, unless it is clear that one point cannot be used for more than one square. Theorically, and if the point is not close to a border, a point can be used by up to four squares.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I agree that may be a problem. I asked about it under the question since OPs original code may match 1 square only (and mark the used points as "used") when there are 3 possible squares. - I've asked again now to make it clear what OP needs.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I didn't get a 100% confirmation so I added an alternative that shows all possible squares.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well, I need to take a break to research and understand your answer. Now I understand about 30% of it...

Comment: @В'ячеславІванчук I haven't checked what effect extracting the node at the beginning of the outer loop in `FindSquares` and reinserting it at the end of loop will have. I suspect that it will be faster than having the `if(sit == fit) continue;` check in the inner loop. I will update the answer if I get the time to try it out. You can also try it with your real data to see if it's faster or not.

Comment: @В'ячеславІванчук Surprise surprise ... Extracting the node from the outer loop to be able to skip `if(sit == fit) continue;` in the inner loop was actually a tad slower in the 1777x1057, 15000 points test I just tried. With more points, it starts paying off. With 30000 points, extracting the node is noticeably faster. Conclusion: For 500 points - do not extract and reinsert the node in the outer loop :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have one question about this line of code: – 
`if(lit = points.find(candidate); lit != points.end())` what if instead of semicolon I would write `&&` is that the same?

Comment: @В'ячеславІванчук That'd be perfectly fine. I prefer to use the new init statement to separate the assignment from the condition checking even when it's not needed.

Comment: That'd be something like `if( (lit = points.find(candidate)) != points.end() )` (I'm on my phone and can't see properly).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Can you explain to me your Point class template? Because previously i made just a simple structure"point" with  x and y. I would learn more to make it work

Comment: @В'ячеславІванчук I made it a template because I don't know what kind of integer you use. The `operator==` and `operator!=` member functions are there to be able to compare `Point`s and `operator-=` is there to be able to implement the free function `operator-` which in turn is used to make vectors like `BA = B -A`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to test for any combination of 2 initial points. Let us call them A and B. But as you only want each possible square once, you can require the third point, let us call it C, to verify (AC) is (AB) turned with 90° in trigonometric sense. If a possible candidate could be obtained by turning in the opposite sense, you would find the final square from a different initial pair.

But here the condition is damned simple:

- yC - yA = xB - xA and
- xC -xA = - (yB - yA)

And when you have a possible candidate for point C, point D will have to verify (CD) = (AB) meaning:

- xD - xC = xB - xA and
- yD - yC = yB - yA

But if you use floating point values for your coordinates, you could fall in an accuracy problem. We all know that floating point arithmetics is <del>broken</del> inaccurate. So you should define an *epsilon* value (generally 10<sup>-6</sup> is an acceptable value) and replace all equality tests with code close to:

```
if (abs(x - y) < epsilon) ...
```

I cannot currently write and test code (no access to a acceptable compiler) but this algorithm should slightly reduce time: operations are much simpler and as you only search the 4th point if you have found an acceptable 3rd one the complexity should be closer to n<sup>3</sup>.

Comment: it works well with straight squares, but won`t with rotated. For example A(2;1), B(5;3), C(3;6), D(0;4).

Comment: That is in computer graphics  coordinate system(without negative coordinates)

Comment: @В'ячеславІванчук : it does work. The image of AB by my rotation is AD: 4 - 1 is 5 - 2 and 0 - 2 is -( 3 - 1). The square I would find is ABDC with your point names.

Comment: ok, I will retry this

Comment: Wait, isn't ABDC would look like letter Z?If the A is at the top, down right is B, then C at the bottom and D down left. Now I'm confused a bit